# multiple java.exe's when restarting android studio

Tags: java, windows, android-studio, taskmanager

I ve noticed that when you exit android-studio and look in taskmgr - you will see that  process studio64.exe is terminated , while java.exe is still running (probably doing nothing 0% cpu use)  and consuming about 400Mb of ram.

So when you start android studio again it launches another java.exe and if you close android-studio - the second java.exe stays in memory along with the first one, consuming memory but not loading cpu. If you repeat steps it just adds another java.exe

Question is, is it safe to terminate old java.exe processes?

**EDIT** 
looks like google fixed that strange behaviour/bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't prove whether it's "safe" or not, but I've terminated many java.exe processes that keep running after exiting Android Studio without any problems whatsoever.